# Problem with extracting values from vector for for loop

Tags: julia

I am trying to extract values from a vector to generate random numbers from a GEV distribution. I keep getting an error. This is my code

```
x=rand(Truncated(Poisson(2),0,10),10) 
t=[]
for i in 1:10 append!(t, maximum(rand(GeneralizedExtremeValue(2,4,3, x[i])))
```

I am new to this program and I think I am not passing the variable x properly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding what you are trying to do, you might want something more like

```
x = rand(Truncated(Poisson(2),0,10),10) 
t = Float64[]
for i in 1:10 
    append!(t, max(rand(GeneralizedExtremeValue(2,4,3)), x[i]))
end
```

Among other things, you were missing a paren, and probably want `max` instead of `maximum` here.

Also, while it would technically work, `t = []` creates an empty array of type `Any`, which tends to be very inefficient, so you can avoid that by just telling Julia what type you want that array to hold with e.g. `t = Float64[]`.

Finally, since you already know `t` only needs to hold ten results, you can make this again more efficient by pre-allocating `t`

```
x = rand(Truncated(Poisson(2),0,10),10) 
t = Array{Float64}(undef,10)
for i in 1:10 
    t[i] = max(rand(GeneralizedExtremeValue(2,4,3)), x[i])
end
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Which materials do you recommend will be a starting foundation to understand Julia.

Comment: One recommendation would be the [Think Julia](https://benlauwens.github.io/ThinkJulia.jl/latest/book.html) book/pdf. While I haven't tried it myself, I've also heard good things about https://juliaacademy.com/, and for my own idiosyncratic perspective there is https://github.com/brenhinkeller/JuliaAdviceForMatlabProgrammers